# Hibernate cache preventing changes from appearing

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I am working with 2 entities. Let's call the entities `Company` (database table `companies`) and `Employee` (database table `employees`). The 2 entities are associated in a many to many relationship. Thier associations are held in a database table - lets call it `company_to_employee`.

The `Employee` object contains no references to `Company` while the `Company` object contains the following for it's association to `Employee`.

```
// Inside Company.java
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "company_to_employee", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "company_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") })
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

I have a database query that is run when a user logs in which grabs the active companies that they own.

```
public List<Company> getActiveCompanies(String userId) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Company> query = builder.createQuery(Company.class);

    Root<Company> company = query.from(Company.class);
    Join<Company, CompanyUser> owner = company.join(Company_.owner);
    Join<CompanyUser,User> user = owner.join(CompanyUser_.user);

    Predicate predicate = builder.and(
            builder.equal(user.get(User_.id), userId),
            builder.equal(company.get(Company_.enabled), true),
            builder.equal(owner.get(CompanyUser_.enabled), true));

    query.where(predicate);

    query.orderBy(builder.asc(builder.lower(company.get(Company_.name))));
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

The returned list of companies is used by the front end to display companies along with their employees, etc.

I recently added a new `enabled` field onto `Employee`. However, the employees on the companies returned by the above query do not pick up changes to this field.

```
@Column(name = "ENABLED")
private boolean enabled;
```

I've tried replacing the query's last line with the following with no luck (caching hint).

```
return entityManager.createQuery(query).setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", false).getResultList();
```

I've also tried updating the mapping to `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` but this also did nothing. And the two attempts did nothing in combination with one another.

The only way I've been able to fix the issue is to add the following to the beginning of the query, but I'd rather not have to flush the whole cache like this.

```
entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).clear();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is `getActiveCompanies` runs in its own transaction or are there any other operations happening in that transaction which runs `getActiveCompanies`?

Comment: It did not have the transactional annotation on it. I added `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` but it did not resolve the issue.